# Git error "fatal: cannot store pack file error" after setting up svn-remote

Tags: git, svn

I have a central Git repository to which I'm trying to push from a local repository. I've never had any issues pushing to this central repository before. But recently I started mirroring the central repository with a Subversion repository following [this procedure](http://www.codeography.com/2010/03/17/howto-mirror-git-to-subversion.html). I did not, however, make the svn repo read-only. Now, after doing that, I get the following error when trying to push my work from my local Git repository:

```
remote: error: unable to write sha1 filename
./objects/pack/pack-874a77bb6a53059 2b8da72598517904b73843aa2.pack:
Permission denied remote: fatal: cannot store pack file error: unpack
failed: index-pack abnormal exit
```

The config file for the central repository looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://subversion/svn/repo/trunk/
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

Does anyone know what's happening? I even tried removing the [svn-remote "svn"] section from the config file but that did not fix it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you visit your git repository in the shell... who owns the directory containing the pack files?  Is there a chance that the subversion process somehow interacted with your Git repo as the wrong user (maybe as root, for instance), and left the directories with the wrong owner, and now you can't write there anymore?  Fixing the damage this one time may be as easy as `chown`ing a few directories.  Fixing it permanently with an ongoing Subversion interaction may be harder.

Comment: It still shows the right owner (myself). Ownership among all files in the local and central repositories is consistent.